# PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity

Tags: php, magento2.2, magento-enterprise, no-such-entity-exception

> **FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity. in
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/WebsiteRepository.php:80
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/Website.php(46):
>   Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->get('dev') 1
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(140):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Website->getAllowedStoreIds('dev') 2
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(126):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->readStoresData() 3
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(89):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData() 4
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
>   Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId() 5
>   /var/www/html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
>   Magento\Store\Model\Stor" while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 127.0.0.1, server: local.dev.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1",
>   upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "local.dev.com"**

I'm facing this issue, when the magento EE V2.2.0 installing in my local system. 
Anyone, Please let me know how to fix this issue??

Comment: remove your generation and cache and try again. some times they create a such cases

Comment: It is not worked out

Answer (score 0):

First of all search the location from where the exception is coming then comment the 'try & catch' code block then it will show you exact error for further debugging. Eg: suppose this your code :

```
 try {
      $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
     } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
      return false;
    }
```

then comment like:

```
 //try {
      $product = $this->productRepository->getById($product);
    // } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
      return false;
    //}
```